# Causing infinite loop on property value change in MAUI

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am working on Xamarin to MAUi conversion.
The below code causes an infinite loop in MAUI at the same time works fine in Xamarin.

```
     private async Task<bool> IsValid()
   {
       try
       {
           bool lValid = false;
           //DataRow dr;

           ItemID = ItemID.Trim();


            if(!isValid)
            {
                  await DisplayAlert("Item '" + item + "' is not valid );
                  ItemID = "";
            }    

           if (!lValid)
           {
               ItemID = _Item.Trim();
           }
           return lValid;
            }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }

    private string _oldItemID = string.Empty;
private string _itemID = string.Empty;
public string ItemID
{
    get => _itemID;
    set
    {
        _itemID = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemID) ? _itemID.Trim() : _itemID;
        value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.Trim() : value;
        if (value != _itemID)
        {
            _oldItemID = _itemID;
            SetProperty(ref _itemID, value, nameof(ItemID));
        }
    }

}
```

If I remove ItemID = ""; it works fine.

IsValid calls from scanned entry command

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to add [breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022) at `ItemID = "";` and `set{}`, what is the value of `ItemID` in each position.

Comment: My guess is that this line `value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.Trim() : value;` is causing the problem. I don't think the special variable `value` should be assigned. Try creating a new support variable.

Comment: @RiccardoMinato  I tried but no difference set
{
    _itemID = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_itemID) ? _itemID.Trim() : _itemID;
    var value1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.Trim() : value;
    if (value1 != _itemID)
    {
        _oldItemID = _itemID;
        SetProperty(ref _itemID, value, nameof(ItemID));
    }
}

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT it's empty "" or new value in each loop

Comment: @Eric The flow is a little bit complex for the handling of a `Entry`. It's not easy to understand why this is happening, but the loop is probably caused by the setter being called by `IsValid()` and vice versa. You probably can get a hint adding a breakpoint on line `if (value != _itemID)` and check why they're found to be different.

Comment: I also noticed that there is another variable `_Item` after `ItemID = "";` that is used to assign `ItemID`. Could it be related?

Comment: What is the effect about `value`？ If the `_itemId` is empty, value would give a valid string to ItemID, right?